# O que é Initial commit?

Tags: git

Estou aprendendo a usar o Git, e queria entender o que é essa linha initial commit que parece na vídeo aula que estou vendo porém está diferente no meu ambiente.

Quero entender pra que serve e como configurar (quero deixar como initial commit, se isso faz alguma diferença, obrigado)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Initial commit é só o primeiro commit que foi realizado no projeto, não?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Provavelmente seu professor já deu algum commit e neste escreveu "Initial commit", no projeto em sua máquina ainda não existem commit's, para acertar de um commit

```
git add .
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
```

Pronto, seu retorno ficará igual.

**Git add**

O `git add` adiciona arquivos ao commit, o `.` avisa que serão todos.

[Leia Mais](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)

**Git commit**

O `git commit` envia para o versionamento local da sua máquina, já o `-m` lhe permite colocar uma mensagem na sequência.

[Leia Mais](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)

Obs: O nome "Initial Commit" é um nome comum de se usar em novos commits, significa "Commit inicial" existem até textos falando sobre este costume.

[Leia Mais](http://www.masalmon.eu/2017/02/21/firstcommit/)